# Insertonsubmit method asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I want insert a row in my table with linq in asp.net, and I've some troubles with that. I search a lot about this and I found the same solution in everywhere:

`context.entity.InsertOnSubmit(variable);`

So, I haven't the InsertOnSubmit method, I need do something special to use it? I have `using System.Web.Linq`.

To overtake this problem I tried with:

```
context.entity.Add(variable);
context.SaveChanges();
```

And the result was an error like:

> "An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details."
>   DETAILS:
>   "Invalid object name 'ConnectionStringModelStoreContainer.user'."

What do you suggest?

Answer (score 1):

1. InsertOnSubmit is a `Linq2Sql` concept to add rows to the database. SubmitChanges is used to save the changes.
2. Entity.Add is an entity framework concept. Save changes is used.

In your case, it looks like you're using `Entity Framework.`

Check your EDMX file and database to see any table mismatches.

Specifically,

1. go to your connection string (in config or better would be via breakpoint)
2. Log in to that SQL Server using that exact connection string
3. Verify if the user table exists there.

Answer (score 0):

When using Linq2SQL, you will need to access the table you are trying to insert into with `context.TableName.InsertOnSubmit(value)` where TableName is the name of the table in your dbml file and the value is an isntance of that class that was created for you.  Once you have called the `InsertOnSubmit()` method, you need to call the `context.SubmitChanges()` method to actually save it to the table.  Also, depending on how you created your dbml file, the table name on the context my be plural.  ex: For a `User` table, it may look like `context.Users.InsertOnSumbit(user);`

Comment: the table name is user and the entity is users. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You seem incredibly confused as to which ORM you are using.  In your visual studio project, do you see a file that ends in .dbml or .edmx?  That is the first step.

Comment: Ok, then you should have access to a DbContext that is setup when you are creating you models.  In order to access your table and insert a new entity you will want to do something like this.  context.Set<Users>().Add(user);  and then finish with context.SaveChanges();

Comment: I apologize, I feel this has gone too deep too quickly.  I'm going to post a new answer soon to lay it out better.  Unless someone else beats me too it.

Comment: I do like this?
context.Set<user>().Add(createUser);
context.SaveChanges();

I tried but gived the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution of my problem.

In this article explain exactly what I need to do:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/29/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-4-add-attach-and-entity-states.aspx?Redirected=true